Reviewing low-quality answers: list of choices is inadequate
For reviewing a low quality answer, we're offered three choices:

Looks OK:
This is an honest attempt at answering the question and is not low quality.
Edit:
Improve and correct problems with this post yourself.
Recommend deletion:
This post cannot be fixed and should be deleted.

A post with a very terse (e.g. no references or explanations) but possibly correct answer can be fixed, but only by doing enough research that one might as well post one's own answer.
E.g. a recent answer consists entirely of "Unitarians, Christadelphians and Ebionites..
Why isn't there a choice (other than "Skip") for handling such answers?

I've tagged this as "bug", because in general the choices in a list should be mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive, and this list certainly isn't.

I imagine a comment explaining the need for additional references/explanations. IIRC, this will then activate the Other choice.
